Is there any way to create custom URLs for windows exe files?
I am currently working on a pyqt application which converted to exe using pyinstaller and I want to create a custom URL similar toms-paint:// for this app.
I tried editing registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and added URL protocol. Also created sub keys (shell/open/command) and added my {exe_path} “%1”.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
